# Microsoft Excel Encounters Error after opening userform or running a long section of code. Is there a fix?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I had no problems with my VBA user form until recently but based on some piece of code or the sheer length of the code is causing Excel to crash when attempting to run. This form is used to gather information from budget owners who we need to supply more information than just financial and we wish them to not have to make any major calculations. 
  Recently, when I launch the code the workbook goes white and says Excel has encountered an error and gives me the option to recover the file.
(unsure if this is related but it seems that my code may be preventing the user from hitting the x in the excel application nor allowing them to user the save as button. When they click nothing happens)

I have tried previous versions with success on the oldest files which did not contain many lines of code, no close user form feature, and no save user form feature.
If I step through or open Visual Basic window prior to running code I experience no issues.
If I save the file as a different file immediately after opening workbook then it works everytime.

```
Sub Call_Userform()
'Unhide All sheets    
Call unhidesheets
Sheets("Headcount").Select

'Opens the Userform
Test.Show
End Sub
_________________________________________________________
Sub unhidesheets()
'Variables
Dim ws As Worksheet
'Unhide sheets
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
__________________________________________________________
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Variables
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Data")

'Department specific accounts allowed
If ws.Range("B1").Value = "625 - Bedre Manufacturing" Then
   Me.MultiPage1.Pages(8).Visible = True 'Product Development
ElseIf ws.Range("D1").Value = "217 - Business Support Center" Then
   Me.MultiPage1.Pages(8).Visible = True 'Product Development
ElseIf ws.Range("D1").Value = "216 - Health Branding" Then
   Me.MultiPage1.Pages(8).Visible = True 'Product Development
ElseIf ws.Range("D1").Value = "964 - Outreach" Then
   Me.MultiPage1.Pages(8).Visible = True 'Product Development
ElseIf ws.Range("B1").Value = "978 - Tribal Health" Then
   Me.Trvlexp.Visible = True 'Travel Expense
   Me.trvlexpenselbl.Visible = True 'Travel Expense label
ElseIf ws.Range("D1").Value = "103 - Deputy Secretary of Commerce" Then
   Me.Trvlexp.Visible = True 'Travel Expense
   Me.trvlexpenselbl.Visible = True 'Travel Expense label
Else
   Me.MultiPage1.Pages(8).Visible = False 'Product Development
   Me.Trvlexp.Visible = False 'Travel Expense
   Me.trvlexpenselbl.Visible = False 'Travel Expense label
End If

'Populate lists with present data
If ws.Range("J2") > 0 Then
    List7005.RowSource = "acct7005"
End If
If ws.Range("J3") > 0 Then
    Listtrvl.RowSource = "accttrvl"
End If
    If ws.Range("J4") > 0 Then
    List7120_1.RowSource = "VehTag"
End If
If ws.Range("J5") > 0 Then
    List7120.RowSource = "acct7120"
End If
If ws.Range("J6") > 0 Then
    List7200.RowSource = "acct7200"
End If
If ws.Range("J7") > 0 Then
    List7230.RowSource = "acct7230"
End If
If ws.Range("J8") > 0 Then
    List7270.RowSource = "acct7270"
End If
If ws.Range("J9") > 0 Then
    List7330.RowSource = "acct7330"
End If
If ws.Range("J10") > 0 Then
    List7335.RowSource = "acct7335"
End If
If ws.Range("J11") > 0 Then
    Costs7510.RowSource = "Phonecosts"
End If
If ws.Range("J12") > 0 Then
    List7620.RowSource = "acct7620"
End If
If ws.Range("J13") > 0 Then
   List7640.RowSource = "acct7640"
End If
If ws.Range("J14") > 0 Then
    List7670.RowSource = "acct7670"
End If
If ws.Range("J15") > 0 Then
    List7710.RowSource = "acct7710"
End If
If ws.Range("J16") > 0 Then
    List7780.RowSource = "acct7780"
End If
If ws.Range("J17") > 0 Then
    List7790.RowSource = "acct7790"
End If
If ws.Range("J23") > 0 Then
    List7790_1.RowSource = "Vehlease"
End If
If ws.Range("J18") > 0 Then
    List7880.RowSource = "acct7880"
End If
If ws.Range("J19") > 0 Then
    List2000.RowSource = "acct2000"
End If

'Bring in last records
If Worksheets("Headcount").Range("B1").Value = "" Then
Else
Me.cb_bus = Worksheets("Headcount").Range("B1").Value
Me.cb_dept = Worksheets("Headcount").Range("D1").Value
'Report Kronos date
Me.tb_test.Value = Worksheets("Headcount").Range("I1").Value
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub    
_________________________________________________________________
Private Sub cbsave_Click()
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
fileFilter:="Text Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
If fileSaveName <> False Then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
    Filename:=fileSaveName, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End If

End Sub
__________________________________________________________________
Private Sub closeform_Click()
'Variables
 Dim ws As Worksheet
'Hide sheets
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Sheets("Start and Instructions").Visible = True
Next ws
If Sheets("Start and Instructions").Range("CA1").Value = "Complete" Then
    Sheets("TM1 Upload").Visible = True
    Sheets("CapEx").Visible = True
    Sheets("TM1 Upload").Select
End If

'Close User Form
Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Step through the code and see which line is giving you the error

Comment: Then update your question with the error and the line it occurrs on...

Comment: The length of the code is not a problem. My largest project may hold 30 times as much code as in your example. Sometimes, lines of code cause Excel to crash. In rare cases, the workbook is corrupted. I'd do what @SiddharthRout suggested and step through the code using `F8`

Comment: NOt sure if it'll help, but I've seen cases where using RowSource causes havoc. Best to use `List7880.List = Range("acct7880").Value`

Comment: If I step through the VBA code I never receive any error. Only when I try to run it from ActiveX Macro Button or select run in the VBA Macros menu. Also, I only provided the snippets of code that I thought might be causing the problem and where the error is found. Entire Userform code lines are 7,175. I will try switching the Rowsource to .list